# Yes/ No :Does $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} n^2 x^2 e^{-n^2|x|}$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} n^2 x^2 e^{-n^2|x|}$ is  uniformly convergent  on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

My attempt  :  I put $x =  \frac{1}{ n}$ , then $n^2 .\frac{1}{ n^2} e^{-n^2 . \frac{1}{n^2}}= e^{-1}$  but $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ is diverge  so it  is not uniformly  convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

Is its true ?

Comment: you put $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in you exponent although you said $x=\frac1n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake: $e^{-n^{2}/n}=e^{-n}$.

It is uniform convergence: We know that $e^{u}\geq1+\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}$ for $u\geq 0$, so
\begin{align*}
n^{2}x^{2}e^{-n^{2}|x|}\leq n^{2}x^{2}\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-1}n^{4}|x|^{2}}\leq n^{2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{n^{4}}=\dfrac{2}{n^{2}},
\end{align*}
the rest follows by Weierstrass M-test.